# Troubles starting Tryton client

Tags: tryton

I use tryton 2.6 to run Gnuhelath in my dad's clinic.

I have installed the tryton server in ubuntu and can use it from the client installed in 5 other Pcs running windows 7 or 8.

But I have a trouble in just one machine. It started ok for a few times, but then the Pc crashed and after that, when I double click on it's icon I got this message:

Error: No option 'database' in section: 'Gnuhealth'

File "tryton", line 66, in

File "tryton\client.pyc", line 101, in run

File "tryton\gui\main.pyc", line 910, in sig_login

File "tryton\gui\window\dblogin.pyc", line 579, in run

File "ConfigParser.pyc", line 618, in get

Hope somebody an help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you still facing this issue? I feel you should reinstall tryton client on your machine.

Comment: It looks like tryton client was trying to read saved profiles when this error occurred. I am not sure where does windows stores this file, maybe <SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.tryton, but linux has ~/.config/tryton. Remove this directory and try, it should work.

Comment: I can't find any file or configuration folder, the only folder exists in C:\Program Files (x86)\tryton-3.2.6\. I even tried to find a config file related to tryton or the profiles.cfg searching in the whole pc, but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file of the client seems to be corrupted.
You can find it under %APPDATA.config\tryton
The easy way to fix it is to delete the file, a new one will be created automatically with default values.